# How is COSMOS possible?

Tags: c#, clr, cil

I just saw that [COSMOS](http://www.gocosmos.org/index.EN.aspx) is an OS written in MSIL langage, and I just wonder how that is possible? I always thought that MSIL needed a CLR to work, and CLR needed an OS behind it.

Thanks for explanations.

Comment: Who said the CLR needs an OS? It's just an instruction set for a relatively sophisticated machine that knows objects, exceptions, concurrency, etc.

Comment: why is it so difficult to make others CLR like Mono?

Comment: I think a more interesting question is how garbage collection is handled.  I believe they also state they have a basic GC.

Comment: Well, you don't create an MSIL JIT-compiler in one weekend, but I imagine that **way** more effort went into recreating all the libraries of the .NET framework (and, to a lesser degree, into a good JIT, as opposed to a naive implementation).

Comment: Re: "Why is it so difficult to implement the CLI spec?" Have you read the CLI spec lately? It's like five hundred pages of dense text. It's a lot of work because the CLR does a *lot* of stuff! We've had hundreds of people working on it for over a decade.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I refer you to the second and third sentences of the Wikipedia article on COSMOS, which I reproduce for you here:

> Cosmos is an open source operating system written in C#. It also encompasses a compiler (IL2CPU) for converting Common Intermediate Language (.NET) bytecode into native instructions. The operating system is compiled together with a user program and associated libraries using IL2CPU to create a bootable standalone native binary

Comment: @Orf: IL2CPU runs on an ordinary Windows box, presumably. It *generates a binary* that can then be installed on the customer's machine. IL2CPU is an OS developer tool, not a part of the operating system.